# Could gdb start with attaching to a process?

Tags: debugging, process, gdb

Without the need of starting gdb first and then attach to an existing process. Is there a one shot gdb command line option to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by using the below command

`$ gdb <executable_file> -p <pid>`

It will attach the `gdb` to process `pid` which is created after executing the `executable_file`.

In some situations `<executable_file>` can be omitted from the command line, in which case gdb will locate the executable file on its own, and read its symbols.